# Domain indexed by Google when using WPGraphQL to fetch content from our WordPress installation

Tags: seo, domains, wordpress, duplicate-content, blog

I have a WordPress blog at `https://example.blog` domain. My main website domain is `https://example.in`.

I am using WPGraphQL to fetch posts from the WordPress blog to my main website developed in React JS.

Which domain will be considered by Google crawlers for the SEO? Is it my blog domain or my main domain?

Comment: Can you browse your WordPress site on its own, or is the content only available through the WordPress API?

Comment: To put what Stephen said a different way, do you have two standalone websites with duplicate content, or is the WordPress blog not a public website or otherwise hidden from crawling in some way?

Comment: I have two standalone websites